# Почему скролиться страница при открытии модального окна?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Использую плагин модальных окон Remodal JS, на этом сайте - [сайт](http://1ceh.razrabotki-h1-studio.ru)
На главной странице в этом месте открытие модальные окна
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://toster.ru/q/543856 если не понятно - для чего выбираете ответ как решение ?

Answer (score 2):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изменил oferflow - на значение visible